# Accept 'Esc' Escape as input in BlueJ?

Tags: bluej

So I have been typing a project for my ICSE Board Exams in BlueJ and I wanted to add the feature of being able to exit to main menu by pressing the **Esc** key. Any idea on how to do that? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you register an event handler for when your menu is active, listening to the escape key.

Comment: Really sorry to ask this stupid question, but how do you create an event handler and how to use it? A video demonstrating this perhaps? I haven't been taught Event Handler in my Course. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery listener for the "Escape" key.

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
   alert('Esc key pressed!');
}
});
```

You can specify a div instead of using the whole document.

Comment: I did use this but my teacher said I can't because, "jQuery is not in the Syllabus." I did present the argument that jQuery is technically JavaScript but to no avail. Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: I am not familiair with BlueJS.